# Editing link in WordPress using Python/Selenium

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

I'm trying to edit a link on a page in WordPress, as part of automating a larger process.  I've managed to log into the admin dashboard, upload a new file, and get the URL for that new file.  Now I need to go and update a link on a specific page to point to that file.

Normally I do this all 'manually' via the admin dashboard for that page.  I'm trying to do it with Python/Selenium, but I'm getting stuck on figuring out how to edit that link.

Edited for an update; here is what I have for as a relatively self-contained code example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://example.com/wp-admin')

assert 'Log In' in browser.title

wp_login = browser.find_element_by_id('user_login')
wp_login.send_keys('admin')

wp_passwd = browser.find_element_by_id('user_pass')
wp_passwd.send_keys('foobarbaz')

wp_submit = browser.find_element_by_id('wp-submit')
wp_submit.click()

assert 'Dashboard' in browser.title

# Open up the Newsletter page in 'Edit' mode
browser.get('http://www.example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=6&action=edit')
assert 'Edit Page' in browser.title

header = browser.find_element_by_tag_name('h4')

header.click()

edit_button = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dashicons-edit')

edit_button.click()

txtBox = browser.find_element_by_class_name('editor-url-input')

txtBox = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#editor > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div > div > form > div > input[type="text"]')

txtBox.clear()

txtBox.send_keys('http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/lorem-ipsum.pdf')

submit = browser.find_element_by_class_name('dashicons-editor-break')

txtBox.submit()

updateBtn = browser.find_element_by_class_name('editor-post-publish-button')

updateBtn.click()
```

Where things are breaking down is around the `txtBox` section... sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I can't consistently get it shift the focus to the text box and clear it.  Sometimes, while I'm manually clicking on things to try and peek at the class names, selectors, etc. it'll work.  But when I run the lines start to finish, that's where it hangs up with the following error:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#editor > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > div > div > div > div > div > form > div > input[type="text"]"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be possible that your driver is not able to find the element by link text. You can try other ways of identifying the element.
For example:

`find_element_by_id`,
`find_element_by_partial_link_text`
`find_element_by_xpath`

and so on. You can refer to https://www.techbeamers.com/locate-elements-selenium-python/ for detailed examples

Answer (score 0):

If identifying elements using partial text/xpath still doesn't work for you, I typically just use macros with AppRobotic to maximize the browser window to keep x/y coordinates relative to the screen the same, identify the x/y coordinates with its UI tool, the move the mouse to those coordinates and click. From there, it's easy to update the element:

```
import win32com.client
x = win32com.client.Dispatch("AppRobotic.API")
x.MoveCursor(100,100)
x.MouseLeftClick
x.Type("{BACKSPACE}")
# wait 200 milliseconds
x.Wait(200)
#Type 'test' while waiting between each letter
x.Type("t")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("e")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("s")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("t")
x.Wait(200)
x.Type("{ENTER}")
```

Comment: Sorry, not interested in Windows-only solutions.  Thank you, though.